# How can I display Row Number in Cross-Tab?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, crosstab

I'm looking for a way to display row number in my cross-tab.

I tried searching online for the answer on how to do it but I haven't found anything useful.
So I'm turning to the good people on Stack Overflow.
The reason that I want to do this, if it's even possible, is because many clients in the company I started working at asked to have a row number in the cross-tab.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Crystal Reports.
So is there any basic ( easy ) way to do this in Crystal Reports?

For example, I have a cross-tab that displays unit of measure and amounts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY7ew.jpg

But I would like my cross-tab to be like:

```
             Amount
1. Total        -38

2. KG 

3. kut            9

4. LIT.           4

5. m            -32

6. proc

7. Koм          -19
```

Please keep in mind that I only started working with Crystal Reports this week, so this is all new to me. And the cross-tab in the picture is just a random one I made to explain what I need.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add a saperate column to the existing cross tab?

Comment: Like I sad I would like to have row numbers in my cross-tab. If another column is what I need then yes I would like to add a separate column to achieve what I need. So the next question that I have for you is how do I add a separate column that will show row number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show Row Number in your CrossTab you will need to first put Row Number in the Stored Procedure that sends data to your report.

In order to understand it better i will first show you how my data looks before i add a Row number(Pic 1).

Code:

```
select 
     a.S_ID as ID,
     osn.sifra as BasicGoodsCode,
     osn.naziv as BasicGoods,
     null,
     a.RobaSifra as GoodsCode,
     a.Roba as Goods,
     a.Detalj as Detail,
     a.DetaljDodatak as DetailsAddon
from NP_Stavke s
     left join RobaGrupe osn on osn.id = s.RobaId
     left join #A a on a.S_ID = s.Id
order by BasicGoodsCode, ID
```

[Pic 1: As you can see I have 3 different Ids for BasicGoods which means that I have 3 Rows in my CrossTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoVsc.png)

Columns ID, BasicGoodsCode and BasicGoods are going to be Rows in my CrossTab.

Values from column DetailsAddon are going to be my columns in CrossTab.

Columns GoodsCode, Goods and Detail are going to be values in my CrossTab.

Column Pieces is not important.

**Now that you know how everything looks we can start with adding a Row Number to our CrossTab.**

**Step 1:**

First thing that you need to do is to add a Row number in table in your stored procedure.
To do this I used [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
depending on your data you might need to use ROW_NUMBER() or maybe even something else. I used DENSE_RANK() because I needed my row number to change once S_ID changes.

Code:

```
select 
     a.S_ID as ID,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY osn.sifra, s.Id asc) as BasicGoodsRowNo, // THIS IS ADDED
     osn.sifra as BasicGoodsCode,
     osn.naziv as BasicGoods,
     null as Pieces,
     a.RobaSifra as GoodsCode,
     a.Roba as Goods,
     a.Detalj as Detail,
     a.DetaljDodatak as DetailsAddon
from NP_Stavke s
     left join RobaGrupe osn on osn.id = s.RobaId
     left join #A a on a.S_ID = s.Id
order by BasicGoodsCode, ID
```

Lets take a look at how our data looks now([Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmXnb.png))

As you can see we added a Row Number that changes when Id changes.

**IMPORTANT:** *Row Number has to be ether Integer or Decimal in the DataTable that you are using in your report if it's not it will not work correctly.*

**Step 2:**

We've done the 'hard' part now it's time to put Row number in our CrossTab.

When you create a CrossTab or when right click CrossTab and then click on 'Cross-Tab Expert...' it will open a window like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e33Gk.png) and in it in the Row section you will insert your Row Number Column(in my case and as you can see in the code above the name of my Row Number Column is 'BasicGoodsRowNo').

**Step 3:**

Since you don't want to show only the Row number in the report left click on your Row and then click on 'Group Options...'([Pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Way49.png))

Once the new window appears click on 'Options' tab then check the 'Customise group name field' then click on 'Use a formula as group name' and then on 'x-2'([Pic 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUIDT.png))

**Step 4:**

Enter a formula like this one:

```
toText( {myTbl.BasicGoodsRowNo}, 0, "" ) + '. ' + {myTbl.BasicGoodsCode} + ' ' + {myTbl.BasicGoods}
```

Of course your formula will not be exactly like mine since you will not have the same columns as I do. The only part of this formula that you HAVE to have is **toText( {myTbl.BasicGoodsRowNo}, 0, "" )** where instead of **{myTbl.BasicGoodsRowNo}** you will put your row number column. You will need **toText** since if you dont have that and you want to show a String after your Row Number it will give you an error because RowNumber is an integer field.

**GJ YOU ARE ALL DONE AND IT WASN'T THAT HARD WAS IT**

[How My CrossTab looks once RowNumber is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MTeq.png)

**Now there is a way to simplify this process and that is:**

**Step 1:**

In your stored procedure create 2 columns. One will show Row Number and the other will show Value that will be displayed as CrossTab row.

Code:

```
select 
      a.S_ID as ID,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY osn.sifra, s.Id asc) as BasicGoodsRowNo, // RowNumber
      CONVERT(varchar(10), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY osn.sifra, s.Id asc)) + '. ' + osn.sifra + ' ' +osn.naziv as BasicGoods, // Value that will be displayed in CrossTab Row
      null as Pieces,
      a.RobaSifra as GoodsCode,
      a.Roba as Goods,
      a.Detalj as Detail,
      a.DetaljDodatak as DetailsAddon
from NP_Stavke s
      left join RobaGrupe osn on osn.id = s.RobaId
      left join #A a on a.S_ID = s.Id
order by BasicGoods, ID
```

As you can see Column BasicGoodsRowNo did not change and will still display the same values as before and I have deleted the clumns BasicGoodsCode and BasicGoods and replaced them with this

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY osn.sifra, s.Id asc)) + '. ' + osn.sifra + ' ' +osn.naziv as BasicGoods,
```

The BasicGoods column will show BasicGoodsRowNo + BasicGoodsCode + BasicGoods.

**Step 2:**

Step 2 is the same as before.

**Step 3:**

Once you click on your row and on 'Group Options' go to 'Options' tab again then check the 'Customise group name field' check box again and after that instead clicking on *'Use a formula as group name'* click on 'Choose from existing field' and from a combo box select the column you want to show as Row Value in your CrossTab. In my Case that is 'BasicGoods' column ([Pic 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ureAe.png)).

*I used the first method since depending on what user decides I may not show CrossTab at all and I may not show BasicGoods but if you only have CrossTab in your report you can use the second, shorter and easier, method.*

If you have any questions feel free to ask.